# Apache Web Server - How do I make my index page point to one of the folders

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I have establish a web server on ubuntu.I have created some web sites on apache, each site has different folder.
In order to browse to my site website1 for example I need to type mymachine/Website1.
I want to type mymachine and it will redirect to the folder website1 , i.e. to my website.
Any suggestion, tried several settings.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to it with Virtual hosts option,
first: you need to make specific folder in /var/www/..
second: point your folders with ServerName in Virtualhost file